# Old Stack Overflow icon is still using in the Android app reputation widget

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app, android-app-widgets

In the Android app reputation widget, the old Stack Overflow icon is still using there.

Can this to be replace with new Stack Overflow icon or the Meta Stack Exchange icon?

Screenshot for reference:

[image: widget icon]

- App Version: 1.0.93
- Device Manufacturer: motorola
- Device Model: XT1033
- OS Version: 5.1 (2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this! The image has been updated to use the Stack Exchange icon as of version 1.0.94 going live right now.

Comment: Verified in `1.0.94`, The SE icon is updated. After update the app need to clear the cached data to see the icon change.